# Angular2 View Not Updated After Local Storage Variable Added

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a login component which when a user logs in, the current User details is stored in a local Storage variable. So when login is successful will store the current User details in a local Storage Variable and navigate to dashboard, i have used the local Storage variable to get the user details and display in Header of webpage, but view is not changing once i refresh the page i will..

```
  login() {
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, 
     this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.activeModal.dismiss();
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            },
            error => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
            });
 }
```

In Service

```
  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: 
     username, password: password }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep 
               user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
   }     

   getCurrentUser() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
   }
```

In Navigation Component

```
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    getUser() {
      this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser();
    }
  }
```

View

```
  <li *ngIf="currentUser"><a href="#">Welcome {{currentUser.firstName}}</a>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="currentUser"><a href="#" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
  <li *ngIf="!currentUser"><a href="#" (click)="openLoginModal()">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="!currentUser"><a href="#" (click)="openRegisterModal()">Register</a></li>
```

Solution I found is to use DoCheck lifecycle hook.
ngDoCheck gets called to check the changes in the directives in addition to the default algorithm

```
 ngDoCheck() {
    this.getUser();
 }
```

Comment: At first sight it all looks good. Is local storage saving your data when logging in?

Comment: i think you missing 'return' inside service 'login' method (inside "map" callback) so the subscribe will fire AFTER localstorage stored: try to add 'return user' after 'localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));' statement

Comment: dont use anchor elements as buttons -_- !